# How can I jump to a specific line without using labels?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

Say I have a call function which returns, can I make it so that it returns to x lines before the return address? eg.

```
call foo --> line 72 - calling bar will return here.
mov ax,1
call bar --> line 74

bar:
mov ax,2
ret (-2)
```

My goal is to create a callable function that will always return to 2 lines before the call address without having to use a billion flags and labels.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You can't, x86 instructions are variable length**.  There's no way to know how much to decrement your return address by to go backward 2 instructions before the `call`.

Even if you were willing to write a disassembler / decoders, there's no way to *unambiguously* decode x86 instructions backwards.  e.g. if you go back one byte and see a `0x90`, you don't know if that's a NOP or the last byte of `add dx, 0x9000`.

Decoding forwards from known function-start labels is what debuggers like GDB do.  But scanning a symbol table and disassembling is way too heavy-weight to be practical for whatever you're doing, I assume.

---

The only thing that occurs to me is being very rigid in your calling sequences so that's always a fixed number of bytes; e.g.  here you used two 3-byte instructions (`call rel16` and `mov ax, imm16`) before `call bar`.  And the `call bar` itself is also 3 bytes.

Or to just always go back by a fixed number of bytes before the return address, and leave it up to callers to choose which / how many instructions to put in that window.

---

And BTW, the way you'd do this is by modifying the return address on the stack:

```
pop ax            ; could use any register that your function destroys
sub ax, 9
push ax
ret
```

Or address it relative to `BP` if you've set up BP as a frame pointer, like `sub word [bp+2], 9`.

---

See [What methods can be used to efficiently extend instruction length on modern x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48046814/what-methods-can-be-used-to-efficiently-extend-instruction-length-on-modern-x86) for techniques to make instructions longer without adding more instructions, in case you want to use a shorter instruction like `mov cx, bx` before a call.  e.g. you can instead use `lea cx, [byte 0 + bx]` (NASM syntax: `byte 0` forces a disp8 of `0`, so the encoding is `8D 4F 00`).