# GNU assembler override size of immediate operand

Tags: assembly, x86, disassembly, gnu-assembler, immediate-operand

I am trying to match a specific sequence of bytes with GNU assembler. Objdump disassembles these bytes as:

```
81 e2 66 00 00 00       and    edx,0x66
```

However, GAS "helpfully" assembles this instruction more efficiently:

```
83 e2 66                and    edx,0x66
```

How can I force GAS to use the less efficient 32-bit immediate operand form? I know if I was using NASM, I could use the `strict` keyword. Is there an equivalent keyword for GNU assembler?

Comment: Section [9.16.4](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dMnemonics.html) of the manual might be of help.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48046814/what-methods-can-be-used-to-efficiently-extend-instruction-length-on-modern-x86) might also be of some help.

Comment: I tried the {disp32} and {nooptimize} prefixes but they didn't have any effect. They also mention `strict`, which is NASM-specific, and the `b`/`w`/`l`/`q` mnemonic suffixes, which are ATT-specific. Were there other suggestions in those links I've overlooked?

Comment: Probably GAS doesn't have an override for that.  Even NASM syntax doesn't AFAIK have a way to round-trip `add al, 1` that uses the 3-byte `add r/m8, imm8` encoding (with modrm) instead of the shorter `add al, imm8` special-case encoding.  I seem to recall someone commenting on a previous SO question that they were thinking of developing an asm syntax for x86 that could represent every encoding choice, allowing round-tripping binary to asm and back without change, unless you edit the asm.  But I don't remember which post that was on, and IDK if that project ever went anywhere.