# x86_64: When is `movzbq` preferable over `movzbl`

Tags: assembly, x86-64

On my `x86_64` machine,
I used `objdump -d` to check the encoding of the following two instructions:

- `movzbl (%rdi),%eax`: encoded in 3 bytes (0f b6 07)
- `movzbq (%rdi),%rax`: encoded in 4 bytes (48 0f b6 07)

Because of implicit zero extension of upper 32 bits for 32-bit operands,
`movzbl` would achieve the same data movement task as `movzbq` **but with 1 less byte of encoding**.

When would the compiler prefer to use `movzbq` over `movzbl` despite that `movzbq` takes up an extra byte ?

Comment: I don't think there's ever a reason to use it. The reason it exists is that it is simpler for the decoder to not have a special case to prevent it.

Comment: When the compiler wants to align the following  instruction, it can insert an unnecessary prefix instead of a separate nop instruction.

Comment: Basically just [What methods can be used to efficiently extend instruction length on modern x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48046814)  - never better than `movzbl` with an unnecessary REX prefix with no bits set, e.g. a `0x40` instead of `0x48` REX.W.  But if you (or a compiler) is generating asm source instead of machine-code directly, `movzbq` will get GAS to use an extra prefix byte as @prl says, even with `as -Os` surprisingly.  There's no downside to a 4-byte `movzbq` vs. a 4-byte `movzbl` on any CPU I'm aware of, but no upside either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When would the compiler prefer to use movzbq over movzbl despite that movzbq takes up an extra byte ?

Whether `movbq` takes up an extra byte depends on the registers used. For example, `movzbl (%rdi),%r8d` is encoded as `44 0f b6 07` (because the "REX prefix" is needed to select `r8`) and `movzbq (%rdi),%r8` is encoded as `4C 0f b6 07`.

This gives 2 slightly different cases:

a) It can be 1 byte shorter. In this case there's no valid reason to choose the longer `movzbq` and compilers that do this (when optimization is enabled) are simply bad at instruction selection.

b) It can't be 1 byte shorter. In this case there's no reason to choose one or the other - it makes no difference at all.

For both of these cases; for "compiler developer's convenience" a compiler's decisions are likely to lean towards symmetry with `movsbl` and `movsbq` (where there is an actual difference).